# How to perform bicubic interpolation using scipy.ndimage.zoom?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, interpolation, bicubic

So I'm using [scipy.ndimage.zoom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.zoom) to resize a 3D volume. However I would like to understand better the `mode` parameter. From the documentation it can have the following values:

```
{‘reflect’, ‘grid-mirror’, ‘constant’, ‘grid-constant’, ‘nearest’, ‘mirror’, ‘grid-wrap’, ‘wrap’}
```

1. Reasoning, `constant` with `order=1` might represent a bilinear interpolation. What do the other modes represent?
2. Also, how can I perform a bicubic interpolation?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.zoom) clearly explains what the mode parameter does and what each of the possible strings mean.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking about BICUBIC interpolation. The documentation doesn't mention it :)

Comment: I would be glad if you could help me to understand how to perform a bicubic operation with it @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 0):

`order` represents the degree of the interpolant. `1=bilinear`, `3=bicubic`. This is independent of the `order` setting.